# How to trigger an action upon change of state?

Tags: salt-stack

I am testing `salt` as a management system, using `ansible` so far.

**How can I trigger an action (specifically, a service reload) when a state has changed?**

In Ansible this is done via `notify` but browsing `salt` documentation I cannot find anything similar.

- I found `watch`, which works the other way round: *"check something, and if it changed to this and that"*.
- there is also [`listen`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#listen-listen-in) which seems to be closer to my needs (the documentation mentions a service reload) but I cannot put together the pieces.

To set an example, how the following scenario would work in `salt`: check a `git` repo (= create it if not existing or pull from it otherwise) and if it has changed, reload a service? The Ansible equivalent is

```
- name: clone my service
  git:
    clone: yes
    dest: /opt/myservice
    repo: http://git.example.com/myservice.git
    version: master
    force: yes
  notify:
    - restart my service if needed

- name: restart my service if needed
  systemd:
    name: myservice
    state: restarted
    enabled: True
    daemon_reload: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example:

```
ensure my service:
  git.latest:
    - name: http://git.example.com/myservice.git
    - target: /opt/myservice
  service.running:
    - watch:
      - git: http://git.example.com/myservice.git
```

When there will be change in repo (clone for the first time, update etc.)
the state will be marked as "having changes" thus the dependent states - 
`service.running` in this case - will require changes, for `service` it means to restart

What you are asking is covered in [salt quickstart](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt2.html)

Comment: Thank you. I read the documentation (this is how I got hold of `watch`) but I have a tremendous problem to understand the logic of the interactions. In Ansible it is done via "flags" (if the state of the  block changes,  `notify` something). I will read the whole thing once again to try to understand. Your example is great as a sterter and I have something to relate to but why `git: http://git.example.com/myservice.git` works is the mystery (I do not see a link with the local repo, it looks like the access to `http://git.example.com/myservice.git`was somehow monitored)